# Продвижение сайтов с разными языками

Tags: продвижение

Интересует реальный опыт. Есть сайт на русском языке. Необходимо такую же услугу продвигать на другом языке. Вопрос в следующем, будет ли достаточно перевода содержимого сайта с тем же дизайном, изображениями, структурой страниц и системой управления на отдельном домене? Или для продвижения лучше целиком переработать проект? Не повлияет ли на выдачу идентичность содержимого, за исключением текстовой информации?